# Is it possible to create a website which emulates a (small scale) Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, browser

I am doing a lot of computer work for a company but I am not currently permitted to use a terminal because I'm not a software developer.

I think I can easily get around this by using an in-browser command line like Eclipse Theia or maybe GitPod.

However, out of curiosity, I was wondering if it would be possible to create a small-scale Linux terminal inside a web browser. I.e., since I cannot install applications, I could get the "program" for a terminal inside my computer by loading it as a web page. The web page could be hosted on a home computer and accessed via an IP address. However, it's not a remote / virtual computer. Instead, the code is sent to the browser, and it's run like an application inside the browser. You cannot save files for use after the window closes, but you can still have a set of useful tools available by default for each use instance.

Is this theoretically possible?

Comment: [JSLinux](https://bellard.org/jslinux/)? Or [something else](https://www.makeuseof.com/best-websites-run-linux-in-web-browser/)?

Comment: If you have no admin rights what would be the purpose of your terminal?

Comment: @ChanganAuto I could definitely use command line tools that are useful but that don't manipulate my filesystem, at least that would be the hope. For example, I can retrieve text from web pages or files and process, edit, or manipulate it with tools like w3m, Vim, Python, then copy and paste it or email it out. That's just one idea. In general, anything you can do with a terminal - command line tools - except for manipulating my work computer's filesystem.

Comment: [The 10 Best Websites to Run Linux in a Web Browser](https://www.makeuseof.com/best-websites-run-linux-in-web-browser/).

Comment: I think JSLinux was the most exact answer to what I had in mind, that is indeed running linux inside a web browser. Very cool, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few other ideas.

1. If you could access a website running some "terminal emulation" in your home computer, you should be able to get a RasPi and access that remotely
2. If your home computer is Windows 10 Pro, you could run an actual Linux on it with WSL
3. If you don't want to install WSL, Cygwin is another option.
4. Yet another alternative to WSL and Cygwin is running a Linux Virtual Machine. WSL, Cygwin and a VM are separated from the host, so to do something in the user home directory to mess up the host requires you to intentionally allow access to the host's file system.
5. You could get an actual remote shell access from [grex.org](https://grex.org) or other shell provider
6. You could use for example [Amazon AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/) or similar to create yourself a real, personal Linux system you can access remotely
7. One alternative to AWS is [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) - you can create a personal Linux system, and have a browser-based full terminal access to the shell
8. [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/doc/terminal.html) offers an online Linux terminal you access with your browser - I'm sure more providers can be found by googling

... or you could just talk to the company and ask them to allow VM, Cygwin or WSL. Based on your comment to @ChanganAuto you might be able to present an actual business case to validate the need.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Shell In A Box](https://www.tecmint.com/shell-in-a-box-a-web-based-ssh-terminal-to-access-remote-linux-servers/). It has to be installed on some Linux machine, then you can connect to that machine via a browser (to port 4200 via default) and have a "normal" terminal access. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: That might be a pretty useful addition to an AWS, Linode or a RasPi :-)